# Text inside a button is getting cut on window resize

Tags: html, css, sapui5

I am stuck in a rather simple looking problem. This is an existing code piece that I am trying to make changes to so that it doesn't break upon resize. I have a button inside which there is a text. On window resize, the button gets shrunk,and my text gets clipped.
The front-end is in SAP UI5 and I am running the application through the browser. Here is a snippet of my code in UI5.

```
var oMatrix = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayout({layoutFixed : true, height : '100px', columns : 2 });

var oCell = new sap.ui.commons.layout.MatrixLayoutCell();
var oButton = new sap.ui.commons.Button({text : "VERY VERY VERY VERY LONG TEXT"}).addStyleClass("oButtonStyle");;

oCell.addContent(oButton);
oMatrix.createRow(oCell,"");
```

The styling to the above is as follows :

```
.oButtonStyle{
 width: 90%;
 direction: inherit;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 15px;
 display:block;
 }
.oButtonStyle .Txt{
  text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
  width: 175px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here, "txt" is a style class that gets applied to any text within that button.

Upon minimising the window, i can only see "VERY VER". I have used the overflow,white-space and the display block as well. I can't figure out where I am going wrong. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what are you trying to do? copied your code to this http://jsfiddle.net/XkTU4/, and it seems to work fine when resizing.. atleast in chrome

Comment: Voting to close this question as `sap.ui.commons` should be avoided. This question is outdated and thus less likely to help future readers. The author abandoned SO.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you don't need a span element inside the button.

Here are 2 possible solutions.

1. Remove the nowrap, which will cause the button to change to 2 or more lines when you resize the window, thus growing in height.

`.buttonStyle{ width: 90%; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; }`

here's your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E8aQb/3/).

-or-

1. Add min-width. That way the button will shrink until a certain point and will stay the same after that. Beware of this solution because it can break your styles at certain point, but that depends on your code and is totally avoidable.

`.buttonStyle{ width: 90%; text-align: left; min-width: 275px; }`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E8aQb/1/) available.

EDIT: sorry had, the link mixed up.

Comment: If you do width 50% in your first link it doesnt work and text gets cut off...wtf